# Can not set pNext to be NULL

Tags: c, vulkan

I am trying to set up Vulkan in C. But then I create my `VkInstanceCreateInfo` and set `pNext` to `NULL` I get an error.

The Vulkan [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkInstanceCreateInfo.html) states 'pNext is NULL or a pointer to a structure extending this structure.' but when I set pNext to be `NULL` I get this error telling me that `pNext` has to be `NULL`.

> Error
>
> `VUID-VkApplicationInfo-pNext-pNext(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 1223396377 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkApplicationInfo-pNext-pNext ] Object 0: VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x48eb8c19 | vkCreateInstance: value of pCreateInfo->pApplicationInfo->pNext must be NULL. This error is based on the Valid Usage documentation for version 154 of the Vulkan header.  It is possible that you are using a struct from a private extension or an extension that was added to a later version of the Vulkan header, in which case the use of pCreateInfo->pApplicationInfo->pNext is undefined and may not work correctly with validation enabled The Vulkan spec states: pNext must be NULL Objects: 1 [0] 0, type: 3, name: NULL`

> Code
>
> ```
>  ...
>
>  VkInstanceCreateInfo vulkanInstanceCreateInfo;
>  vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
>  vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.pNext = NULL;
>  vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
>  vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &vulkanApplicationInfo;
>  vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
>  vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;
>
>  /* validation layers */
>  if(VALIDATION_LAYERS_ENABLED){
>    vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = validationLayersCount;
>    vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers;
>  }else
>    vulkanInstanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
>
>  ...
> ```

Comment: You did not set the `pNext` of the `vulkanApplicationInfo` though.

Comment: Yup, that worked. I'm sorry but I just went right over the fact that it said VkApplicationInfo and thought that it was talking about VkInstanceCreateInfo. I feel really stupid about having this problem for over a day but thanks a lot for pointing it out to me. @krOoze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not talking about the `VkInstanceCreateInfo` but about the `VkApplicationInfo`. I did not set my pNext there.